# Needing to hot update VScode for Javascript to update react elements' transformations using browser window properties

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have some code from a tutorial to create a parallax effect on a webpage. The tutorial didn't use react, but I did for my project. The code looks like the following:

```
const parallax_el = document.querySelectorAll(
".parallax"
  ) as NodeListOf<HTMLElement>;
let xValue = 0,
yValue = 0;
window.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
xValue = e.clientX - window.innerWidth / 2;
yValue = e.clientY - window.innerHeight / 2;
  });
parallax_el.forEach(
    (item) =>
      (item.style.transform = \translateX(${-xValue}px) translateY(${-yValue}px)`) );`
```

As the title suggests the images with parallax in their className won't update their positions unless I Ctrl+S in vscode, then it snaps into place based on where my cursor is on the browser window.

At first I thought that react.useEffect was what was missing as I am trying to update the DOM, but upon updating my code to:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
const parallax_el = document.querySelectorAll(
".parallax"
    ) as NodeListOf<HTMLElement>;
let xValue = 0,
yValue = 0;
window.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
xValue = e.clientX - window.innerWidth / 2;
yValue = e.clientY - window.innerHeight / 2;
    });
return () => {
parallax_el.forEach(
        (item) =>
          (item.style.transform = \translateX(${-xValue}px) translateY(${-yValue}px)`)     );   }; }, []);`
```

the same behavior is happening. There are no errors in the console and I tried console logging the xValue and yValue and it does if the console.log is before the transformation, but if I place it after the transformation then it stops showing and I don't know what is causing this on Javascript side of things.

Answer (score 0):

I was using React.useEffect wrongly, since I passed in an empty array as the second argument, I am only rendering on first frame, but I wanted to re-render upon changes to xValue and yValue as that is when mouse moves. I had to add xValue and yValue to the array in the second argument and it worked.